# No "Add New" Button. How to add new theme?

Tags: themes

[image: screenshot]

Hii,
I don't have the add new button.How to install a new theme?

Comment: Make sure that your theme directory is writable for PHP.

Comment: You can install a new theme Manually (FTP).      https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Themes#Adding_New_Themes

Answer (score 11):

In my case, the button was missing because it was a multisite install. The Add New button appears only when you go to top bar -> My Sites -> Network Admin -> Themes. From there, you can add new themes and enable them for the rest of the network.

Answer (score 3):

edit the file 'wp-config.php'

```
define('DISALLOW_FILE_MODS', false);
```

Comment: Works in fedora 35, wordpress from f35 repository, edit the file /etc/wordpress/wp-config.php

Answer (score 2):

Edit config file
Go to cpanel -> File Manager -> wp-config.php 
Click on edit

Scroll to the bottom 
Change
define('DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', true);
define('DISALLOW_FILE_MODS', true);

to 
define('DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', false);
define('DISALLOW_FILE_MODS', false);

This fixed it for me

Answer (score 1):

Themes are just sub-folders in `wp-content/themes`, when you upload a theme in a zip file to the themes page, it just unzips the file into that folder. If it's a valid theme then it shows up on that page.

If for whatever reason this functionality is disabled, or write access isn't possible, that option won't present itself in the user interface, but I would recommend using the manual process instead

Answer (score 1):

Never ran through such problem but I can suggest you to do the following:

If you are a linux user:

```
$cd path_to_your_wordpress_site/wp-content/
ls -lah
$sudo chmod -R 755 themes
```

Here h flag to ls command will show you all the ownerships and permissions related to the file.
If it didn't help either

go to the root directory of the web server:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data your_wordpress_site_folder
```

above command is for ubuntu

for centos

```
$sudo chown -R apache:apache your_wordpress_site_folder
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

This might be the problem. 
The feature only exists for wordpress.ORG and not for sites exists on WordPress.COM

Comment: This could be the issue for someone else, but the OP's screenshot indicates that the site is being run via localhost, so it's a .org site in this case.

Comment: Okay. Yeah. My mistake. It was for me :)

Answer (score 1):

**Why does this happen?**
It usually happens, if you enable

> Softaculous Apps Installer> WordPress> Enable Multisite (WPMU),

In this case, Wordpress creates 'Network Admin' alongside 'Admin' for using WPMU. Which allows you to upload the theme from 'Network Admin' only.

**What to do now?**

Simply re-install and make sure you haven't enabled the option like the image below.
[image: WPMU]

**What if I wanna use the option?**

You can simply go to their official website [WPMU](https://premium.wpmudev.org/) and learn how to use the features in details.

Answer (score 1):

define('DISALLOW_FILE_MODS', true); - this was my case, but it wasn't in the wp-config.php, instead, it was in the theme's functions.php file!